# Pattern matching on a website URL with Pandas DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to solve a slightly complex project with `Pattern matching` for a website URL.

I have a particular column that contains URL with several information embedded inside the URL. I am not getting this accurately I keep getting errors.

Here is an example of what I am trying to solve. I have a column called Page from `Google analytics` data.
It contains rows like this `Mywebsite.com/optiona/optionb/type/102/103/107?data=1.2. 1581202800. 1581289200.30`

```
I want to create new columns containing 
the website - Mywebsite.com
option type a - optiona
option type b - optionb
type of product - type
product1 - 102
product2 - 103
product3 - 107

And ?data= in a separate column 
another new column - 1
new3 - 2
starttime - 1581202800
endtime - 1581289200
age - 30
```

I first tried to split them in a list so it is easy for me to access them:

```
df_analytic["Col_for_analysis"] = re.split(r"/",df_analytic["Page"])
```

But I get: `TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object`

Comment: So what is the code/pattern that fails to work as expected?

Comment: `re.split` second argument should be a string, you are using Pandas, so you should try things like `df_analytic["Page"].str.split('[/?]', expand=True)`

Comment: Try `df_analytic["Page"].str.split(r'\s*\.\s*(?!.*/)|[\s/]+|\?(?:data=)?', expand=True)`

Comment: This works perfectly well, there is only one issue. where the website is missing, it replaces it with the next row of the next column and it shifts like that until the end.

Comment: So what is the input string format then? `optiona/optionb/type/102/103/107?data=1.2. 1581202800. 1581289200.30` and `Mywebsite.com/optiona/optionb/type/102/103/107?data=1.2. 1581202800. 1581289200.30`? What is obligatrory and what is optional?

Comment: They are all obligatrory

Comment: Can you post your sample data? I think you need to split by newline then explode then you can split by url.

Comment: But you have just said "*where the website is missing*". Could you clarify?

Comment: can you check the post again, I updated the post. Please can you check?

Comment: Your question is unclear because you did not show all possible types of input.

Answer (score 1):

Remove data=, split by everything you see:

```
df_split = df['input'].str.replace('data=', '').str.split(r' |/|\?|\.', expand=True).replace('', np.nan).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
then you can rename your columns as you wish.
```

Edit: I added the dropping of empty columns.

Edit2: to take into account the absent hostname, split separately:

```
df_split1 = df['input'].str.split(r'\?data=', expand=True)
df_left = df_split1.loc[:, 0].str.rsplit(r'/', n=5, expand=True)
df_right = df_split1.loc[:, 1].str.split(r'\.| ', expand=True)

df_left['option_a'] = df_left.iloc[:, 0].str.split(r'/', expand=True).iloc[:, -1].fillna(df_left.iloc[:, 0])
df_left['sitename'] = df_left.iloc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: np.NaN if '/' not in x else re.split(r'/', x)[0])
```

then concat

```
df = pd.concat([df_left, df_right], axis=1).iloc[:, 1:].replace('', np.nan).dropna(how='all', axis=1)
```

then do the remaining renaming of the columns.

Comment: Oleg, either fix your solution, or please consider removing the post since your solution does not solve the problem.